# How do I commit and a push a folder opened and edited using Visual studio to github

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, github, cygwin, repository

I have a React-native project I made using Cygwin. The files for it are all in one folder and I used Visual studio to edit the .js files, create new folders etc. I haven't saved the folder as a solution, I just used the open folder option. Now I do I push my work to a github repository?

Comment: have you looked at any guide ? here is github's own guide https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/

Comment: Hello thanks for helping. I ended up deleting the .git folder then used the command line to push the project.